# Dynamic dropdown menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm begginer in RoR. I have doubts in dropdown menus.

Let's say I'm building new form for checkout menu and in first step I have dropdown menu with two possible solutions for User:

1.first_name, last_name, address(taken from already logged in user) also to mention that I have authorized this page before all

2.New Address(if user clicks on that, it will open new form for first_name,last_name etc via jquery)

I don't know how to proceed with these dropdowns, so any suggestion would help

Comment: what are the expected drop down values?

Comment: 1) first_name, last_name. address taken from logged user(<%= current_user.first_name, current_user.last_name => etc)
2)New address(when clicked it should open new form for first_name,last_name etc)

Comment: I dont understand your question. the drop_down options will be old address, new address. am i right?